# Problem running Makefile that calls Perl script

Tags: perl, scripting, makefile, compilation

I'm trying to compile a C++ software a month ago.

There is a lot of pressure to make this work as soon as possible.

I've been looking for similar problems but I'm getting more and more confused.

I'm using the following:

```
bcmsa@braw176 ~/nba >uname -a
SunOS braw176 5.8 Generic_108528-13 sun4u sparc SUNW,Ultra-5_10
bcmsa@braw176 ~/nba >make -v
make -v
GNU Make version 3.79.1, by Richard Stallman and Roland McGrath.
Built for sparc-sun-solaris2.8
Copyright (C) 1988, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 2000
        Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I executed the command:

```
bcmsa@braw176 ~/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default >make -dwp all
```

But I'm receiving the following:

```
Reaping winning child 0x0006da38 PID 27586
/bin/sh: /aps/APS40/RPG3_R4A/lib/cmtool/plugin/rpg3.R3B/tools/tools/scripts/sigunion.pl: not found
Live child 0x0006da38 (/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/sigunion.h) PID 27588
Got a SIGCHLD; 1 unreaped children.
Reaping losing child 0x0006da38 PID 27588
make: *** [/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/sigunion.h] Error 1
Removing child 0x0006da38 PID 27588  from chain.
```

The crazy thing is that sigunion.pl is stored at the indicated directory:

```
bcmsa@braw176 ~/nba >cd /aps/APS40/RPG3_R4A/lib/cmtool/plugin/rpg3.R3B/tools/tools/scripts/
bcmsa@braw176 /aps/APS40/RPG3_R4A/lib/cmtool/plugin/rpg3.R3B/tools/tools/scripts >ls -la
total 120
drwxrwsr-x   2 80422    3626        4096 Jun 12  2002 .
drwxrwsr-x   3 80422    3626        4096 Jun 12  2002 ..
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626        2195 Jun 28  1999 bdt_c.sh
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626        2449 Mar  8  1999 bdt_h.sh
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626         681 Oct 20  1999 change_base
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626         990 Oct 20  1999 convert_to_iog11
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626         692 Oct 20  1999 create_directory
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626         604 Oct 20  1999 create_elements
-r--r--r--   1 80422    3626         582 Mar  2  1999 create_elements.base
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626        2059 Dec 13  2001 generate_signal_files.csh
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626         486 Oct 20  1999 generate_version_info
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626         610 Oct 20  1999 get_program.csh
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626         760 Oct 20  1999 get_suid.csh
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626         774 Oct 20  1999 set_autostart.pl
-r-xr-xr-x   1 80422    3626        1555 Oct 20  1999 sigunion.pl
```

Please, help me find how to fix this fault.
I really don't know what else to do.

I tried to execute the following just to see what happens:

```
bcmsa@braw176 /aps/APS40/RPG3_R4A/lib/cmtool/plugin/rpg3.R3B/tools/tools/scripts >perl sigunion.pl
Can't exec /usr/atria/bin/Perl at sigunion.pl line 1.
```

Info:

```
bcmsa@braw176 /aps/APS40/RPG3_R4A/lib/cmtool/plugin/rpg3.R3B/tools/tools/scripts >which perl
/usr/bin/perl
bcmsa@braw176 /aps/APS40/RPG3_R4A/lib/cmtool/plugin/rpg3.R3B/tools/tools/scripts >perl -v

This is perl, version 5.005_03 built for sun4-solaris


bcmsa@braw176 /aps/APS40/RPG3_R4A/lib/cmtool/plugin/rpg3.R3B/tools/tools/scripts >head sigunion.pl 
#! /usr/atria/bin/Perl
```

Comment: That's a huge amount of content that obscures the problem. The only relevant bits are the line in the makefile that attempts to invoke the script (which you didn't include!), and the resulting error message.

Comment: Sorry for that, but I put all the information where my analysis stopped. I couldn't find so far where is the macro AUTOCREATE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the shebang in sigunion.pl (aka the #! line) is pointing to the wrong place for your perl executable.

`head sigunion.pl` will show you where sigunion.pl thinks perl is, and `which perl` will show you where perl is actually installed.

Example:

```
$ head sigunion.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
.....stuff omited
$ which perl
/usr/opt/perl-5.8.8/bin/perl
```

Answer (score 3):

> /bin/sh: /aps/APS40/RPG3_R4A/lib/cmtool/plugin/rpg3.R3B/tools/tools/scripts/sigunion.pl: not found

...indicates that /bin/sh could not figure out how to run the script sigunion.pl. It is probably missing a shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

...which tells the shell what external program (in this case, perl) to parse and run the file.

Alternatively, you can just let `perl` be found in the `$PATH`, by changing the appropriate line in the Makefile to:

```
perl /aps/APS40/RPG3_R4A/lib/cmtool/plugin/rpg3.R3B/tools/tools/scripts/sigunion.pl <arguments>
```

Comment: @Jonathan: agreed, sometimes `/usr/bin` is not the right location.

Comment: which platform does not have `env` in `/usr/bin`?  I checked: Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, Linux, MacOS X - all have it in `/usr/bin`.  On Linux (and Solaris) it is *also* found in `/bin`.  Or were you referring to 'sometimes Perl is not found in /usr/bin'?  In which case, I 100% agree with you.

Comment: @Jonathan: I meant the latter. I vaguely recall encountering a situation where shebang lines with spaces were not parsed correctly, but I cannot remember which architecture or shell I encountered this on. Hopefully these issues no longer exist on any modern OS.

Comment: it shouldn't still be a problem (if it is, it is time the hardware was replaced and the o/s upgraded from its decade+ time warp).  The standard for a [shebang](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is "up to 32 characters total with at most one argument separated by spaces from the command", I believe.